# How can I create a custom SQLTransformer in PySpark ML to pivot data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a data frame that resembles the following structure:

```
# Prepare training data
training = spark.createDataFrame([
    (990011, 1001, 01, "Salary", 1000, 0.0),
    (990011, 1002, 02, "POS Purchase", 50, 0.0),
    (990022, 1003, 01, "Cash Withdrawl", 500, 1.0),
    (990022, 1004, 02, "Interest Charge", 35, 1.0)
], ["customer_id", "transaction_id", "week_of_year", "category", "amount", "label"])
```

I'm able to pivot this data dynamically using PySpark follows, which eliminates the need hard code case statements for each week and category:

```
# Attempt 1
tx_pivot = training \
    .withColumn("week_of_year", sf.concat(sf.lit("T"), sf.col("week_of_year"))) \
    .groupBy("customer_id") \
    .pivot("week_of_year") \
    .sum("amount")

tx_pivot.show(20)
```

I'd like to develop a custom Transformer to dynamically pivot data so I can incorporate this custom Transform stage within a Spark ML Pipeline. Unfortunately, the current SQLTransfomer in Spark/PySpark only supports SQL like E.g. 'SELECT ... FROM **THIS**' (refer to https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/ml/feature.py).

Any guidance for going about how to create a custom Transformer to dynamically pivot data would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite straighforward to implement a custom transformer that takes a dataframe and returns another dataframe. In your case:

```
import pyspark.ml.pipeline.Transformer as Transformer

class PivotTransformer(Transformer):

    def _transform(self, data):           
        return data.withColumn("week_of_year",sf.concat(sf.lit("T"),\
                    sf.col("week_of_year"))) \
                   .groupBy("customer_id") \
                   .pivot("week_of_year") \
                   .sum("amount")
```

Comment: What about a Scala version? The function`transformSchema` has to be implemented, but we don't know the output schema in advance as the pivot determines the new columns at runtime.